# Possible to http clone repo to Docker Container?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, docker

I see a lot about ssh'ing down a git repo to a container but what about through https?

I exec to my container as a non-root user.
Then I tried to run `git clone <my proviate git repo url>`

It asked me to auth in, so I typed in my usual username and password for git.

I know it works because I tried it locally in OS X, but when I try through my container, it's giving me remote: `Invalid username or password` for some reason.

Comment: What is the cloned protocol? https? git? ssh?

Comment: @codeWizard I tried https for the protocol when copying my git repo url from github as I normally do when working in OS X but of course this is a docker container running Ubuntu so not sure if I should be able to use https to clone down my repo to a docker container.  I even went back to my github account even though I know the password I'm trying is right, I changed my github password then tried again...same deal, same error.

Comment: Updated the answer according to your inputs

Comment: When you enter the container and try to do the clone you say that it asks for your username and password, but don't tell us what happens. I'm assuming it fails, but how? What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

forgot I was using two factor auth, needed to use a personal token not my github password.

Answer (score 0):

[Pulling git into a docker image without leaving ssh keys behind](http://blog.cloud66.com/pulling-git-into-a-docker-image-without-leaving-ssh-keys-behind/) is a similar article about this issue.

---

According to your comments:

In order to clone the code into your docker using https.
Follow those steps and set this content in your docker file:

- tun off `sslVerify` for your domain
- use http which is a read-only protocol if you can

---

When using `https` you will need to supply password or using a certificate.
In your case you use docker so you have to set it in your docker file

```
// or switch off SSL checks completely by executing:
git config --system http.sslverify false
```

The line will turn off the SSL check

set this in your config to disable it only for the given url and not for all requests

```
[http "https://weak.example.com"]
    sslVerify = false
```

---

#### `http.sslVerify`

> Whether to verify the SSL certificate when fetching or pushing over HTTPS.

---

#### `http.sslCAInfo`

> File containing the certificates to verify the peer with when fetching or pushing over HTTPS

Comment: Verify if there's some file called ~/.gitconfig.lock. If that's the case just delete it.

Comment: no luck, I did what you said.  Right now I'm not using a dockerfile. I created the container using a run command.  I'm learning docker so later I'll come back and use a dockerfile going forward

Comment: Hi there, you can also look on a similar solution here: http://blog.cloud66.com/pulling-git-into-a-docker-image-without-leaving-ssh-keys-behind/

Comment: open your github account and check to see if you have ssh keys there or not.

Comment: I do but I don't think they're being used